# import needed to implement class remains greyed-out at top of file - not usable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-room

I am trying to import the package needed to use this class : databaseBuilder.
The IDE correctly knows that I want to import this ; and offers the autoimport option - but it always stays greyed out at the top - unusable. The databaseBuilder in the code sits there in red - continually offering to import the same package.

I have tried invalidate cahce/restart to no avail.

Minimum code:

```
package com.lbaron.flyingweather
import androidx.room.Room.databaseBuilder
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

abstract class TestClass : RoomDatabase(){
    val instance = MetarDBItem.databaseBuilder(null, MetarDatabase::class.java,
    "metar_database")
    .build()
}
```

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried removing either the import itself or `MetarDBItem.` in front of the `databaseBuilder`?

Comment: @mabako thanks a lot, that seems to have done it. I'm copying an example out so still need to figure out what is happening.

How did you know that would work?

Comment: @LiamBaron imports are a way to create a shorthand for the full package name of a thing you want to use, so what you're trying to call is ``androidx.room.Room.databaseBuilder(ctx.applicationContext...``, i.e. a function called ``databaseBuilder`` on the ``androidx.room.Room`` class. The problem line in your code has you calling a function with that name on the ``MetarDBItem`` class instead. The IDE doesn't recognise a function with that name on that class, and it doesn't match the fully qualified name you're trying to import. Handy to know if you import the wrong ``max`` function or something!

Comment: @cactustictacs yes that is it. Your time to reply is appreciated a lot!